# Запятая: "Ноги, классные."

Tags: пунктуация

Запятую можно ставить там, где я хочу сделать акцент?
Например:
"Ноги классные."
а я имею ввиду:
"Ноги, классные."
Акцент на ногах. Имеется в виду, что сначала ноги (увидел их), а потом уже результат (реакция) - классные, то есть будет ли в таком случае "Ноги, классные" правильно?
Или если я обращаюсь к ногам и говорю, что они классные? В таком случае подойдет запятая?

Comment: @shampar Вопрос корректировали уже два раза, но лучше и понятнее от этого он не стал:  контекста не было?  - и нет,  а ошибки?  -  и ныне там.

Comment: Если вы обращаетесь к ногам (что несколько необычно, но возможно), то лучше сказать: "Ноги, вы классные"

Answer (score 3):

**Запятую можно ставить, если ситуация ясна.** Допустим, вы заблудились в лесу, ваш друг залез на высокое дерево, чтобы осмотреться на местности.

"Ну, что видно?" —  "Озеро, большое".  Запятая показывает последовательность передачи информации.

Поэтому если задаете вопрос, **то давайте полный текст**, не имеет смысла придумывать фрагменты.